# Pattern for '.' separated words with arbitrary number of whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

It's the first time that I'm using regular expressions in Python and I just can't get it to work.

Here is what I want to achieve: I want to find all strings, where there is a word followed by a dot followed by another word. After that an unknown number of whitespaces followed by either `(off)` or `(on)`. For example:

```
word1.word2   (off)
```

Here is what I have come up so far.

```
string_group = re.search(r'\w+\.\w+\s+[(\(on\))(\(off\))]', analyzed_string)
```

`\w+` for the first word

`\.` for the dot

`\w+` for the second word

`\s+` for the whitespaces

`[(\(on\))(\(off\))]` for the `(off)` or `(on)`

I think that the last expression might not be doing what I need it to. With the implementation right now, the program does find the right place in the string, but the output of

```
string_group.group(0)
```

Is just

```
word1.word2   (
```

instead of the whole expression I'm looking for. Could you please give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ ... ]` is used for character class, and will match any *one* character inside them unless you put a quantifier: `[ ... ]+` for one or more time.

But simply adding that won't work...

```
\w+\.\w+\s+[(\(on\))(\(off\))]+
```

Will match garbage stuff like `word1.word2 )(fno(nofn` too, so you actually don't want to use a character class, because it'll match the characters in any order. What you can use is a capturing group, and a non-capturing group along with an OR operator `|`:

```
\w+\.\w+\s+(\((?:on|off)\))
```

`(?:on|off)` will match either `on` or `off`

Now, if you don't like the parentheses, to be caught too in the first group, you can change that to:

```
\w+\.\w+\s+\((on|off)\)
```

Comment: Why even use a capturing group for "(on)" or "(off)"?

Comment: @tenub Perhaps OP is looking to extract this value for further use? They used it in the character class, which could be an indication of needing that value.

Answer (score 3):

You've got your logical OR mixed up.

```
[(\(on\))(\(off\))]
```

should be

```
\((?:on|off)\)
```

`[]`s are just for matching single characters.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets are a *character class*, which matches any one of the characters in the brackets. You appear to be trying to use it to match one of the sub-regexes `(\(one\))` and `(\(two\))`. The way to do that is with an alternation operation, the pipe symbol: `(\(one\)|\(two\))`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may be with the square brackets []
they indicate a set of single characters to match. So your expression would match a single instance of any of the following chars: "()ofn"

So for the string **"word1.word2 (on)"**, you are matching only this part: **"word1.word2 ("**

Try using this one instead:

```
re.search(r'\w+\.\w+\s+\((on|off)\)', analyzed_string)
```

This match assumes that the () will be there, and looks for either "on" or "off" inside the parenthesis.